# Returning image from aspx page fails

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image-processing

i have to return about 46 images from my server. the web page makes several jQuery calls in addition the aspx page renders rotated images. the following is the aspx page code

```
string CaseID = Request.QueryString["CaseID"].ToString();
        string ImageID = Request.QueryString["ImageID"].ToString();
        int RotationAngle = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RotationAngle"].ToString());
        string ImagePath = Request.QueryString["ImagePath"].ToString();

        string fileName = string.Empty;
        FileInfo fi;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CaseID) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageID))
        {
            fileName = "genetics.png";
            fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileName);

        }
        else
        {
            fileName = ImagePath;
            fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName));
        }

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "image/" + fi.Extension;

               Bitmap b = new Bitmap(fi.FullName);
            //   Bitmap image = RotateImage(b, RotationAngle, true);
               b = RotateImage(b, RotationAngle, true);

                using (ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    switch (fi.Extension.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "jpg":
                            b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            break;
                        case "jpeg":
                            b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            break;
                        case "png":
                            b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                            break;
                    }
                   b.Dispose();
               //    b.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
        }
```

the image rotation code is as follows:

```
  public static Bitmap RotateImage(System.Drawing.Image image, float angle)
    {
        // center of the image
        float rotateAtX = image.Width / 2;
        float rotateAtY = image.Height / 2;
        bool bNoClip = false;
        return RotateImage(image, rotateAtX, rotateAtY, angle, bNoClip);
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(System.Drawing.Image image, float angle, bool bNoClip)
    {
        // center of the image
        float rotateAtX = image.Width / 2;
        float rotateAtY = image.Height / 2;
        return RotateImage(image, rotateAtX, rotateAtY, angle, bNoClip);
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(System.Drawing.Image image, float rotateAtX, float rotateAtY, float angle, bool bNoClip)
    {
        int W, H, X, Y;
        if (bNoClip)
        {
            double dW = (double)image.Width;
            double dH = (double)image.Height;

            double degrees = Math.Abs(angle);
            if (degrees <= 90)
            {
                double radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
                double dSin = Math.Sin(radians);
                double dCos = Math.Cos(radians);
                W = (int)(dH * dSin + dW * dCos);
                H = (int)(dW * dSin + dH * dCos);
                X = (W - image.Width) / 2;
                Y = (H - image.Height) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                degrees -= 90;
                double radians = 0.0174532925 * degrees;
                double dSin = Math.Sin(radians);
                double dCos = Math.Cos(radians);
                W = (int)(dW * dSin + dH * dCos);
                H = (int)(dH * dSin + dW * dCos);
                X = (W - image.Width) / 2;
                Y = (H - image.Height) / 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            W = image.Width;
            H = image.Height;
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        }

        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap bmpRet = new Bitmap(W, H);
        bmpRet.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpRet);

        //Put the rotation point in the "center" of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(rotateAtX + X, rotateAtY + Y);

        //rotate the image
        g.RotateTransform(angle);

        //move the image back
        g.TranslateTransform(-rotateAtX - X, -rotateAtY - Y);

        //draw passed in image onto graphics object
        g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0 + X, 0 + Y));

        return bmpRet;
    }
```

the problem i am facing is the i get a strange "invalid parameter" exception. I have made sure the files are all correctly present.

can someone please help? the same code works fine when used in a console application (the console application only converts images)

Comment: Where is located the "Invalid Parameter" exception you describe ?

Comment: At what point do you get this exception ? Can you step through the code, and post the exception details and the line that causes it ? From what I can see your code looks sensible.

Comment: it comes up here  b = RotateImage(b, RotationAngle, true);

Comment: i am wondering if it has something to with the how much rotation angle i am specifying which at the moment can be anything between 0 to 360

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose the problem here is that you are performing your operations in the Page_Load method.

Override the ProcessRequest method, check your query string parameters and then call your current code.

If you meant to send images, return from the method without invoking base.ProcessRequest() after writing the images .

Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: it turned out that the issue was if the angle of rotation was specified to be more than 180. Made it less than 180 and it works fine